# How to import XML data into Javascript for functioning as the data for Heat Map Layer?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

I am trying add a heatmap layer over Google Maps using Google Maps API and have worked out the default documentation given by Google developers successfully. However, I want to add the 'location' and 'weight' via a XML data generated with PHP from MySQL. But I am getting the HTML output with just the Google Map Image and the heatmap layer is not coming. 
     
     
     
    Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Heatmap Layer
    
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas{ height: 100%;}
    
     src="link"

```
 var heatMapData=[];//empty array to store objects
 var heatmap;
 var pointArray;

    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.5697, 88.3697),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

         function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
 }
 function doNothing() {}

 downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml_heatmap.php", function(data) {
       var xml = data.responseXML;
       var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
 for (var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++) { //loop through nodes getting info
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var intensity = markers[i].getAttribute("intensity");
    var hObj =  { //create object
    location: point,
    weight : intensity
    };

 heatMapData.push(point); //push object onto array

          } 
 });
   pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatMapData); //convert array to MVC array
   heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatMapData
    }); //create heat map object

    heatmap.setMap(map); //display heat map on map
}
function toggleHeatmap() {
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
  }

  function changeGradient() {
    var gradient = [
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
      'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
      'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
      'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ]
    heatmap.setOptions({
      gradient: heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient
    });
  }

  function changeRadius() {
    heatmap.setOptions({radius: heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20});
  }

  function changeOpacity() {
    heatmap.setOptions({opacity: heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;">
</div>
<button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
<button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
<button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
<button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
</body>
</html>
```